# 'Shortcut' for actions on objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, action, hidden, shortcut

So I have 3 objects in my project right now:

```
_vLabel.hidden = YES;
_wLabel.hidden = YES;
_nextButton.hidden = YES;
```

As you can see I do the `.hidden` thing for all of them . Is there a way of creating variable or something with which I would only have to apply it instead writing the whole line, like:

```
_vLabel.hide;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Write a method that toggles hidden for all three of them?

Comment: @matt what do you mean?

Comment: You could use `ishidden` method, so [_vLabel isHidden];

Comment: @Pahnev you mean like `_nextButton.isHidden;`? This does not change anything...and Xcode says it is a "getter method"

Comment: Well I'm not sure what you are trying. If you want to hide something you have to call method to do it or make things hidden in Storyboard. There is no magical thing that will hide everything. If you want shorter method, then `isHidden` is already pretty short.

Comment: @Pahnev I just don't want to write the whole long line all the time for each object. But `isHidden` is a getter method as Xcode says, so it does not change anything

Comment: You use it as a method: `[_vLabel isHidden];` not _vLabel.isHidden;

Comment: @Pahnev as I understand it you are off base: those two are equivalent, and get the value of the hidden state without changing it.

Comment: @Pahnev hm no changes either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the question unclear. What would be a "shortcut" in this situation? How can you get any "shorter" than this:

```
_vLabel.hidden = YES;
_wLabel.hidden = YES;
_nextButton.hidden = YES;
```

To me, the "length" here - the thing that needs shortening - is that you're doing something three times instead of once. If these objects are objects that you typically hide and show *together*, then it would be nice to have *one* method that hides and shows *all* of them:

```
- (void) toggle {
    _vLabel.hidden = !_vLabel.hidden;
    _wLabel.hidden = !_wLabel.hidden;
    _nextButton.hidden = !_nextButton.hidden;
}
```

It's just as much code, but once you've written it, then every time you want to show them all or hide them all you just say:

```
self.toggle;
```

Which is itself actually a shortcut for:

```
[self toggle];
```

So what you'd be doing here is writing a method in order to change what the language a little, and that's a perfectly reasonable thing to do if it avoids repetition.

Comment: Great way too! But my aim was more to write one line  to make it a word and then apply it to all

Comment: That would be a lot easier in Swift where you can define a `hide` function and then say something like `[_vlabel, _wlabel_, _nextButton].map(hide)`.

Comment: Oh really? That's great. I should remember this... Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems silly to do it, as you should just follow the convention that any other iOS programmer expects and understands, but yes you can do it:

```
UIView+MyCategory.h:
@interface UIView (MyCategory)
    -(void) hide;
@end

UIView+MyCategory.m:
@implementation UIView (MyCategory)
-(void) hide {
    [self setHidden:YES];
}
@end

usage:
[myView hide];
```

Comment: replace `-hide` with `- (void)hide`.

Comment: Well, it's a useful example of what a category on an existing class can do. And `[myView hide]` can also be written as `myView.hide`, I am still trying to decide my own rule for when I prefer each

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, if your only problem is that writing `label.hidden = YES;` is too long then why don´t you just use code snippets? That way you keep using the naming conventions with less writing.

You can even use Xcode to create these snippets. Just select the text and drag it from the edge(this part can be pretty tricky) to the snippets area.

Personally though I would use something like `TextExpander` or `aText` or whatever else you prefer to do this. These apps are usually faster than Xcode and easier to use.

Just create in those apps snippet for `.hidden = YES;` and assign it to a shortcut like `.hide`
So now whenever you want to hide something you just write `myLabel.hide` TextExpander will expand it into

```
myLabel.hidden = YES;
```

And to make things visible again you could assign `.show` to `.hidden = NO;`